# Spring/JSTL: How to iterate over a map and bind input fields to the values?

Tags: java, spring, jstl, spring-webflow

So my command object has a `public Map<ProductVO, String> availableProducts;` which holds the site's various products/services as the keys and the amount the user wishes to purchase as the values. Normal getter/setter is provided of course.

This map is instantiated (as a HashMap) and populated during a setup step with all products from our database and all the values are initially set to "0".

In the jsp I then have a table to display each product in a row with each row holding the product.description, product.price and then an input field where the user can enter how many of that product they want or just leave it at zero (don't worry about non-numeric validation, will handle somewhere else).

My JSTL foreach looks like this;

```
<c:forEach var="availableProductEntry" items="${credit.availableProducts}">
    <c:set var="product" value="${availableProductEntry.key}" />
    <tr>
        <td>${product.description}</td>
        <td>${product.price}"</td>
        <td><form:input path="${availableProductEntry.value}" /></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

This works fine for display, ie the table appears exactly how I want it, with all products iterated and displayed, description, price and the initial value of the field correct.

However upon putting some numbers in the fields and hitting submit I inspect the command object and it doesn't look like the Map values have been updated, they're all still "0".

I've probably got the `path="${availableProductEntry.value}"` part wrong.

Is there a way to get the dynamically generated input fields to update the values of the Map that they initially pulled their value from?

Comment: Meh ..closed. Been looking an hour for this.

Comment: ew, yah i was looking for this too, still I see no way

Answer (score 2):

you actually need to use this:

```
<form:input path="availableProducts[${product}]" />
```

this is of course if your command object is "credit" which sounds like it is from your post

Comment: Would it not be availableProducts[${product}] as the "Entry" is just that, the entry, while the Map is just availableProducts?

Comment: indeed I got confused by your variables. did it work? I use that with String as keys and it works

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use something like this:

```
<form:input path="${availableProductEntry[product]}" />
```

You need to conform with the JavaBeans naming convention (so getBean() and setBean()) so  you can't use a Map like you did.

Comment: Would it not be ${availableProducts[product]} as the "Entry" is just that, the entry, while the Map is just availableProducts? Are you able to expand on the meaning of your second part? Are you saying that it is not possible to get input fields to set values in maps?